# Fetch All Discord Servers Owners

Tags: javascript, discord.js, owner

So I want to get the name of all the discord server owners that my bot is in. Discord.js v14

I tried using this:

```
const Guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.fetchOwner());
console.log(Guilds);
```

But it returned me this:
`Promise { <pending> }`

I also tried this: [Get server owners from what servers the bot is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097324/get-server-owners-from-what-servers-the-bot-is-in), but it does not work on discord.js v14

Comment: if it's returning a `Promise` then `await` then statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Promise#all()` to wait for all the promises to resolve

```js
const owners = await Promise.all(client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.fetchOwner()));
console.log(owners);
```